# Play Framework Compile sass file manually

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

My question is quite simple, I am  using play framework 2.4 with scala and assetSASS,  I want to allow users to create their owns css so I have several scss files that I import and override default variables with the ones provided by User. I don't have any problem with that and it works nice in local. I create the file, insert my content and like I am in development mode, the file is automatically compiled. But for production mode, I need to compile this file in a method of my Scala controller, can someone help me to manually compile a scss file in order to let me access it via public folder ? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways,

1. using sass gem + exec(!) process in scala

```
    // install sass gem from the command line
    gem install sass 

    // In your controller file
    import sys.process._

    def controllerMethod() {
       "/usr/bin/sass in.scss out.css".! // don't forget the exclamation
    }
```

2. using kkung's sass-scala 
   https://github.com/kkung/Sass-Scala

Comment: Ok I thought I could do this by using a method from the sbt-sassify plugin, or simply by running something like assets command from my controller. 
So I have to use one of these two solutions, in the first method I have to put /usr/bin/sass, this will work even when my application will be on cloud servers ?

Comment: SassCompiler.compile method might help. check out sbt-sassify's tests [here](https://github.com/irundaia/sbt-sassify/blob/master/test/org/irundaia/sass/SassCompilerTest.scala). Installing gem sass will put it in /usr/bin/sass folder by default. Yes, as long as you install the dependencies in your cloud server, it will work.